# Issue with xpath for python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xbmc

Very new with elementtree so i'm trying to parse xml file for tv addon for xbmc. Below is the code that i'm having issue with. I think my xpath is not correct and placeholder is not working on the the attribute!

This is the xml file i'm workig with - http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/episode_list.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&sid=2930

```
    seasonnum = root2.findall("/Show/Episodelist/Season[@no='%s']/episode/seasonnum" % (season))


        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
        import urllib            
        tree2 = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
        root2 = tree2.getroot()
        seasonnum = tree2.findall("./Episodelist/Season[@no='%s']/episode/seasonnum" % '1')
        print seasonnum
```

SyntaxError: expected path separator ([) is what i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import urllib
    content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    tree2 = ET.fromstring(content)
    tvrage_seasons = tree2.findall('.//Season' )
```

Had to work it like this as for some reason in xbmc Elementtree there must be an error or something to not make it work. But this worked out for me!

Answer (score 2):

using ElementTree:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/episode_list.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&sid=2930'
>>> request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Accept" : "application/xml"})
>>> u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>> tree = ElementTree.parse(u)
>>> rootElem = tree.getroot()
>>> [s.text for s in rootElem.findall('.//Season[@no="2"]/episode/seasonnum')]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', 
 '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`xml.etree.ElementTree` documentation - XPath support](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support):

> This module provides **limited** support for XPath expressions for
>   locating elements in a tree. The goal is to support a small subset of
>   the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of
>   the module.

You may need third-part library like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) to use XPath.

Example:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>>
>>> url = 'http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/episode_list.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&sid=2930'
>>> tree = lxml.etree.parse()
>>> tree.xpath("/Show/Episodelist/Season[@no='%s']/episode/seasonnum/text()" % 1)
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
```

**UPDATE**

To use `lxml.etree.ElementTree`, the xpath should be slightly modified:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>>
>>> f = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> tree = ET.parse(f)
>>> [e.text for e in tree.findall("./Episodelist/Season[@no='%s']/episode/seasonnum" % 1)]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
```

Comment: Is there a way to use elementtree as i'm using it for xbmc and that module is already installed

Comment: @Mikewave, I added an alternative that use `lxml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: I've tried that and getting syntaxError: expected path separator ([) i put the code that i use above

Comment: @Mikewave, Indent the code correctly. And please post full traceback if possible.

Comment: @Mikewave, The code works fine. See [a screecast I just recorded](http://asciinema.org/a/7761). The code is slightly modified (`url` added, `root2 = ..` line remove because `root2` is not used).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example and it works. Here is a condensed, complete version:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://services.tvrage.com/myfeeds/episode_list.php?key=ag6txjP0RH4m0c8sZk2j&sid=2930'
tree = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
seasons = tree.findall("./Episodelist/Season[@no='%s']/episode/seasonnum" % '1')

for s in seasons:
    print s.text
```

The only problem I can think of, is somehow, you downloaded a partial XML document--unlikely, but I do not know any other explanations. Note that the above script is taken from your question. I only added the `for` loop.